# Git pushing codes From repository 1 To repository 2(collaborator repository)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, github, git-push

I need some help because I have some codes that I pulled from my repository branch and changed a couple of things in it.

What I need is to push it into another repository that I have been a collaborator in.

Been trying to push the codes, and trying to access it but to no avail.

Can anybody help me with this one? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different repositories where you manage to code. First one from where you clone/pull code and made some changes. Second one is what, where you want to push your latest code.

If you clone your repository from GIT then It automatically attach its GIT Url into your application. To check run this command

```
git remote -v
Result:
  origin   https://username@github.com/project-name.git (fetch)
  origin   https://username@github.com/project-name.git (push)
```

This is url from where you clone/pull your latest code. Now we have created alias of URL as ORIGIN.
so when ever you want to push your code, you will do

```
git push origin master
```

Now Add another GIT URL(remote) where you want to push your latest code.

```
git remote add origin_two https://username-two@github.com/project-name.git
```

So now commit your changes and made a pull request from your secondary GIT URL this way.

```
git pull origin_two master
```

If you got any conflicts then make corrections in code and then again add untracked files using

```
git add file-name
```

add a commit message

```
git commit -m "Your message"
```

and push your code to git

git push origin_two master

If you are working with branches:

You have two repositories now for a single application. So for that each repo has their own branches, to list down branches for each origin just follow

```
git branch -a
```

will list all the branches from two remotes. now If you really want to push on any other branch then you should commit all the changes on current branch an then move to your favorable branch using command

```
git branch branch-name
```

and do code here whatever code you will change now push to particular branch

```
git push origin_two branch-name
```

That's it :) Hope this can help you.

Comment: that really helps thanks, also can i ask what if the code i am pushing is the brach? how to i do that?   I pull from the branch and then push it into the 2nd repository as the main one?

Comment: For that you need to check your current branch. If it is master then just do git push origin_two <branch-name>